# List only open redmine projects via redmine-java-api

Tags: java, redmine-api

I'm using redmine-java-api 3.1.3 in an older project and tried to implement a minor change today, making it list only open (=non-closed) redmine projects instead of all projects.

There seems to be no documentation on this, but I found the property storage that I can retrieve via  `project.getStorage()`. However, I was unable to list existing properties (`getProperties()` does not seem to exist in this version), so I do not even know if I'm on the correct path.

```
   RedmineManager redmineManager = TymyController.getRedmineManager();

   ProjectManager projectManager = redmineManager.getProjectManager();

   try {
            List<Project> projects;
            projects = projectManager.getProjects();

            for (Project project : projects) {
                PropertyStorage storage = project.getStorage();

                /* my temporary output: */
                Logger.getLogger(TymyController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, storage.get(NO_IDEA_WHAT_TO_WRITE_HERE));
```

Any insight on how to list only open projects or available property storage keys would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

redmine-java-api is a wrapper around Redmine REST API. it can use (or at least it can be extended to use ) whatever project APIs are available here https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Projects

feel free to submit a patch for Redmine to support filters when requesting projects list. once that is implemented (in Redmine), you can also add that filter to redmine-java-api library.

also, take a look at javadoc of "getStatus" and "setStatus" method in Project class  https://github.com/taskadapter/redmine-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/com/taskadapter/redmineapi/bean/Project.java#L210